# C# - How can I get the language name from the language code?

Tags: c#, internationalization

I'm looking for a way to get the language name from the language code.

```
en -> English
zh -> Chinese
jp -> Japanese
fr -> French
de -> German
```

etc...

Comment: Just the language name in English, or all language names in all languages?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(new CultureInfo("en").DisplayName);
```

Note that DisplayName will format the name for the currently set language. If you want it to always be in English, use EnglishName.

Comment: MikeP, can this be done the opposite, name to code, like "English" to "en"?

Comment: Note that this is platform dependent and may work inconsistently from computer to computer. It uses OS native list of cultures.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work:

```
var allCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
var en = allCultures.FirstOrDefault (c => c.Name == "en").DisplayName;
var de = allCultures.FirstOrDefault (c => c.Name == "de").DisplayName;
```

[CultureInfo.DisplayName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.displayname.aspx) will contain what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this:
http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/

not sure if it helps.

Comment: this does help, nice top have a full list of supported codes :)